# Ubuntu 22.04 unable to use JetBlue inflight wifi

Tags: networking, 22.04, network-manager, nmcli

I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 running on an Asus Zenbook, exact model UX390UAK. My wifi at home and in coffee shops works fine but on every JetBlue flight I take I'm unable to use their inflight wifi (called FlyFi).

The network connects but the login page (flyfi.com) is unable to load, it appears to fail at TLS negotiation.

Here are things I've tried:

- Change DNS to Google - without this the login portal (FlyFi.com) doesn't resolve at all
- disable IPv6
- disable ufw
- disabled MAC randomization
- update openssl config to allow UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation, allow TLS v1.2, and set Sec level to 1
- various MTU from 500 to 1500
- restarted NetworkManager between all of these steps

Some other details:

- I keep my laptop updated regularly, I was last on a flight in Jan and the same problem occured (also JetBlue)
- Chipset is Intel 8260
- wifi works on phone running Android (same scenario in January)
- testing with `openssl -connect` gives `errorno=104` - it seems the server just isn't sending any data (it also shows messages like `no peer certificate available` and `No client certificate CA names sent`
- running `curl -k https://www.flyfi.com` or when loading in a browser (tested both Firefox and Chrome) it ends up with `Connection reset by peer` while negotiating TLS
- no obviously relevant error/warn messages in journactl nor dmesg

I'm at a loss for what else to try/look into. Any ideas on what could be the root cause or other debugging steps to take?

Comment: Can't help you directly, but a while ago, when I was trying to connect to a WiFi hotspot, I was unsuccessful.  Tech support explained to me that they had made some assumptions about either a Windows or Mac environment.  Thus, there are some default settings that they have assumed which are not compatible with Ubuntu.  (i.e., it isn't possible because they didn't use a more universal setting)  I didn't write down the settings at the time, so I don't have any information for you to search for.  Good luck with this!

Comment: Tether to the phone?

Comment: Have you tried using non-HTTPS HTTP? If on a new browser, either disable HTTPS-only mode for now, or click past the warning

Comment: @OrganicMarble that's another rabbit hole that I wasn't able to get working  got close on my last flight but wasn't up for fighting it this time around

Comment: @DanielT it responds with a 302 to the https site if I try to hit http

Comment: They might have blocked the `curl` user agent. Try setting the user agent. Also try writing a script to manually make the HTTPS request over `openssl s_client` set to verbose to better isolate the problem

Comment: @DanielT using -debug and -trace with openssl s_client shows that it fails writing the first packet to the sever (that's what my interpretation is - not an expert here). Since my laptop doesn't have a connection I can't copy-paste a user agent in but since curl is getting the exact same result as Firefox it doesn't seem to be a user agent issue.

Comment: "Change DNS to Google" You don't want to do that. You want to use their DNS so that the captive portal can intercept the DNS

Comment: @DanielT I'd agree that makes sense intuitively but their DNS just fails completely - the portal fails to resolve if I don't send to Google DNS. Honestly, it's probably the same underlying problem - if I get their DNS working that might fix the portal issue.

Comment: Instead of their portal directly, try resolving `captive.apple.com` and going to the HTTP version in Firefox

Comment: Interesting, I'm able to load Apple's capture portal on both http and https. It doesn't forward me anywhere though.

Comment: Some airports let Apple services through (I downloaded 5GB of apps without logging in). Try `http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt`

Comment: That one didn't work  I just landed so will only be able to debug a bit more. If there are more ideas I'll try them on my next flight though!

Comment: I think the best workaround is to connect to WiFi from your Android phone and use USB tethering as OrganicMarble suggested. Since it's a flight, you always have your charging cable. If your airline hates Linux, they might have used fingerprinting to block the Linux IP packet TTL values, or the SSL connection options.